PostgreSQL JDBC driver throws ClassCastException when storing OffsetDateTime to timestamp with time zone column
I have a PostgreSQL table with timestamp with timezone column.
According to the JDBC 4.2+ spec, the JDBC Type TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE should be mapped to the OffsetDateTime class (and vice versa) by the JDBC driver and no conversion required in the user's code.
And it is working fine for a cases like rs.getObject("ts_col", OffsetDateTime.class);
Although, if I use something like:
create table timestamp_test
(
    id     bigserial primary key,
    ts_col timestamp with time zone
);

insert into timestamp_test(ts_col)
values (now());

with
private final static String selectQuery = "select * from timestamp_test";
@Test
public void jdbcOffsetDateTimeTest()
{
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection())
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectQuery,
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        rs.updateObject("ts_col", OffsetDateTime.now());
        rs.updateRow();
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        log.error("Exception: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

I am getting a ClassCastException here.
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.OffsetDateTime cannot be cast to class java.sql.Timestamp (java.time.OffsetDateTime is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; java.sql.Timestamp is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.setRowBufferColumn(PgResultSet.java:2128)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.updateRowBuffer(PgResultSet.java:2165)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.updateRow(PgResultSet.java:1643)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyResultSet.updateRow(ProxyResultSet.java:69)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.updateRow(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at st.notexi.springtest.DbTest.jdbcOffsetDateTimeTest(DbTest.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

My question - is it supposed to be so or am I just doing something wrong? Like, should it work or should I use something like
rs.updateObject("some_timestampz_column", new Timestamp(myOffsetDateTimeInstance.toEpochSecond() * 1000));

I use Pg JDBC Driver version 42.7.4 (the latest).

Add a [MRE] on the question.

I traced it down to the source code line, isn't it enough? It's clear that pg jdbc driver is simply trying to cast column value of type OffsetDateTime to the java.sql.Timestamp

@aled I'll try but it should take some time which I don't have right now. Unfortunately I cannot share the existing code which is under nda, but it is quite simple. Isn't it clear from the question where and what is the problem really?

OffsetDateTime.now() instanceof java.sql.Timestamp => Error: |  incompatible types: java.time.OffsetDateTime cannot be converted to java.sql.Timestamp

I didn't vote on this question but usually not adding complete errors or missing [MRE] cause people to downvote.

Ok, ty, added it

This question is similar to: How to convert java.sql.Timestamp to java.time.OffsetDateTime?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@aled well, don't know what else could I add. I don't need to convert the calue, I suppose it should work as it is in the example. But I've added a brief clarification. Please tell, is it ok now?

@aled Like, the question you mentiined is about ‘how to convert’. It’s quite simple and trivial, i even added the conversion to my question from the very beginning. My question is about ‘why is it required to convert’, as i think it should be done by the JDBC driver

It seems because the JDBC API was not or can not be extended to support that.

@Abra why does it map it to java.sql.Timestamp when the official PostgreSQL documentation (linked in the question) says it maps to OffsetDateTime?

@BUKTOP what's your JDBC driver version? Also, if what happens if you insert System.out.println(rs.getObject("ts_col", OffsetDateTime.class)); just before the setObject call? (Sorry, I don't have an environment handy to test with at the moment.)

@k314159 Added version to the question. But as you could see on the link to the current source code line, it's still in the master. ResultSet#getObject works fine for OffsetDateTime, just update is causing an error. Well, I filed a bug 3464, will wait for the reply

You might try the other JDBC driver for Postgres: PGJDBC-NG

@BasilBourque May 25, 2021 - do you really think it worth a try?

It sounds like a bug to me, consider reporting it to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver project.

@aled This is in no way a duplicate of that question, which asks how to convert between those types, and this question which asks how to do something which is specified by JDBC. And to be clear, what the OP wants to do is what is specified by JDBC 4.2 and higher, so a compliant driver should support this.

In any case, the problem seems to be that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't really consider TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to be a java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE, but instead a java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, and the implementation in PgResultSet has no handling at all for java.time.OffsetDateTime when updating a row (and simply expects the object that was passed to updateObject to have been a java.sql.Timestamp).

@MarkRotteveel Yes, looks like a bug. As I mentioned above, I've filed it as 3464. Interesting, that it happens only while updating via cursor. Get/setObject works fine

@BUKTOP As a side comment, I'm not sure if you're already aware, but PostgreSQL implements TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE columns by storing only a timestamp in those columns, without any time zone information. It is up to you to hold the time zone, possibly in a separate column. This doesn't invalidate the issue/bug in any way, just clarifying this limitation.

@k314159 Yes, I know that, thank you. I don't actually need a timezone, just a date-time. I supposed driver is casts/converts stored value from UTC to the required TZ and back. Like, timestaamp is kept as utc in the db and converted from the utc to the required timezone and back by the driver

@k314159 Oh my, I have it even in the question. I mean the workaround with toEpochSeconds, which, as I remember, returns the number of seconds since 1970/01/01 00:00:00 UTC
